# Persistant Queue<> or List<> even when program shuts down or restarts

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make an application restart/crash/endtask persistant Queue (or List..). Ie: I need to add things to it when the application runs and remove things at later times. Between these two occations the application can have restarted multiple times (or crashed, or been end-tasked for all I know).

My first thought was to just simply create a `mylist.txt` file to store the data line by line and add lines to the end when I need too and take and remove the first line when I'm done with it.

Problem is that there can be many thousands of lines in the text file after a while and there is no way to just remove the first line in it without reading and rewriting the entire file.

So are there any good ways of accomplishing this, given that continously reading and writing the entire file is not an option?

**Edit 1**: I am looking at SQLite, but I would prefer to not add any more dependencies or .dll's that can't be ILMerged if possible.

**Edit 2:** The application can't depend on any external servers to keep track of things for it.

**Edit 3:** A suggestion of an ILMerge compatible local database would also be an acceptable solution.

Comment: The downvotes here are not clear, as this question is not "egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect"

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution for a persistent queue in software is to use a persistent queue package.

**We call these Message Queue libraries.**

Microsoft Windows has one built in called MSMQ. However I would recommend using RabbitMQ, or, alternatively you could try to use Ayende's Rhino Queues if you want to have an in-proc solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a database, persisting data and editing/deleting it is exactly what they are for and there are some good free ones, try mysql

Comment: This would require me to have a centralized server that all clients communicate with or a local instance on all client pc. Dosent sound too easy.

Comment: @JensB not all databases require a central server or local instance, try looking at databases that use only a local file

Comment: @Aron in a lot of situations, it is fine. If you need something simple, there's no reason to overkill it.

Comment: @EricHotinger because it gives you absolutely NOTHING. I hate programmers who go straight to RDBMS for all their storage needs right off the bat. You do realize that "for something simple", directory filled with files would work with a lower overhead than a RDBMS. You actively have to work against ACID to get simple queuing behaviours in multi user.

Comment: @Aron you're assuming it's multi-user ... if it's one tiny little app that can do it within a simple transaction ... then your argument is nonsensical. And yeah - maybe just using file system is fine too.

Comment: @Aron And i hate programmers who use a cannon to shoot a fly, there's nothing in the question that makes me think he would need something like  MSMQ

Comment: @JoaoFSA so you think that MySQL is lighter weight? MySQL is arguably an even heavier cannon. The only reason you think its lighter is because its your favourite hammer. Prove me wrong, tell me you have used every single feature in MySQL.

Comment: @EricHotinger No. My argument is that all the queuing logic exists in Queuing software. Why reinvent a square wheel when a round one is already in your operating system (and I actually don't mean MSMQ here either).

Comment: @JoaoFSA  or find me someone who has the job title MessageQueueAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

I made my own implementation of this which simply uses files in a folder. It's not the fastest list ever, but it gets the job done with no external dependencies. On my laptop it inserted 4000 items in 4 seconds, and read them back in 12.

Any ideas on how to make this faster or better are very welcome ;)

Heres a test usage:

```
PersistantQueue list = new PersistantQueue("queuefolder");
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 100000))
{
    list.Add(i + "_" + Guid.NewGuid());
    if(i % 1000 == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("c: "+ DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:fff ->") + i);
}

string msg = null;
int b = 0;
while ((msg = list.GetNext()) != null)
{
    b++;

    if (b % 1000 == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("r: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:fff ->") + b);
}
Console.WriteLine("done");
```

And the class

```
public class PersistantQueue
{
    private string _FolderPath = "";
    private long _FileIdCounter = 0;
    private readonly object _LockObject = new object();

    public PersistantQueue()
    {
        Init("PersistantList");
    }

    public PersistantQueue(string folderPath)
    {
        Init(folderPath);
    }

    private void Init(string folderPath)
    {
        _FolderPath = folderPath;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(folderPath.Trim()) == true)
            throw new Exception("Invalid folder name");

        if (Directory.Exists(_FolderPath) == false)
            Directory.CreateDirectory(_FolderPath);
    }

    public void Add(string Item)
    {
        lock (_LockObject)
        {
            _FileIdCounter++;

            string file = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssfff") + "_" + _FileIdCounter;
            string path = (_FolderPath + @"\" + file);
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                sw.Write(Item);
            }
        }
    }

    public string GetNext()
    {
        string result = null;
        lock (_LockObject)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(_FolderPath);

            var firstFileName = di.EnumerateFiles()
                        .Select(f => f.Name)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

            string path = (_FolderPath + @"\" + firstFileName);
            result = File.ReadAllText(path);
            File.Delete(path);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```